# jenkins group while in job is not the same as in terminal

Tags: linux, permissions, jenkins

I have installed jenkins on our dev server, and I added the user "jenkins" to some groups for example www-data.

now when I run this command on the terminal:

```
groups jenkins
```

I get this output

```
jenkins www-data
```

and that is ok, but in one of my jobs I created an ssh command that simply does

```
groups jenkins
```

and the result is

```
jenkins
```

as you can see the "www-data" group is missing, so I have some permissions errors.

Any ideas why this weird bug happens??

Answer (score 1):

Your Jenkins runit setup may be using `chpst` to run as the `jenkins` user with only the `jenkins` group. Check your `/etc/sv/jenkins/run`, if it has `exec chpst -u jenkins -U jenkins`, change it to `exec chpst -u jenkins:jenkins:www-data -U jenkins` and restart

Answer (score 0):

Replying because I had a similar problem but was not running runit.

My system is running remoting - https://www.jenkins.io/projects/remoting/

Problem:

- jenkins got added to wheel and root groups
- Subsequent calls to sudo as jenkins failed
- jenkins was removed from wheel and root, but sudo still failed
- As jenkins user, verified through ssh that the groups were gone
- Adding call to /bin/id as a line in the Execute shell Build script showed that the jenkins user was still member of the groups

Fix: As jenkins user, restart java remoting

- ps -ef | grep remoting
- kill [remoting id]
- cd [jenkins jar folder]
- java -jar remoting.jar -workDir /web/jenkins -jar-cache /web/jenkins/remoting/jarCache

EDIT: There must be a more elegant way to restart the server. I'll update this if/when I find it.